# making list of lists in R

Tags: r

Why in R

```
e=list(a,b,c,d)
```

is different than:

```
e=list(a,b)
e=list(e,c)
e=list(e,d)
```

?

The second approach can be easily used in a for loop, but it produces different result, and I create 1 object each iteration, so cant use first approach, any hints ?

Comment: if you are trying to concatenate two lists you should use `c(list1, list2)` rather than `list(list1, list2)`. The second approach creates a list of length 2 (of two lists).

Comment: Expanding at konvas' comment you might need `c(e, list(c))` (if c is not a list) etc or, better, allocate a list of length 4 and and add a, b, c and, d in corresponding e[[i]] iteratively

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to use this approach, you can do this:

```
# Make up some data
a <- 1:3; b <- 4:5; c <- 6:10; d <- 11:17

# Build up the lists
e0 <- list(a, b, c, d)
e <- list(a, b)
e <- c(e, list(c))
e <- c(e, list(d))

# Compare the two
identical(e0, e) # TRUE
```

In a real-life case, however, instead of using a loop, you probably would be better off using function from the `*apply` family, such as `lapply()`, which will return a list of outputs directly.